# Setting Auth. Token Header AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I'm following the following method to my rails API, and need to send in an authorization token

```
  def restrict_access
   authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    ApiKey.exists?(access_token: token)
  end
 end
```

The token works when  passing in via curl in a header with format:

```
   -H 'Authorization: Token token = "tokenvalue"'
```

I'm having trouble translating this for my AFHTTPRequestOperationManager. How would I define the below to equal the above curl request ?

```
    [self setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];
    [self.requestSerializer setValue:@"tokenvalue" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization: Token"];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Was finally able to get this with:

```
[self.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token token=101010"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Both tokens needs to be on the value side

Comment: I had the issue that I needed to add a space behind "Authorization" ending up using [_manager.requestSerializer setValue:AuthToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization "];